# Squeeze notifications in GCM

Tags: php, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

i have a problem.
i have an android application ( based on Corona).
i am sending GCM notifications to my users when their out of the game.
the major problem is that the number of notifications will be very much and they annoy user.
so what i want is an ability to squeeze notifications to single one with multiple records that each record shows a single notification of my application , instead of have many notifications.
i read the Google GCM references and i found the "tag" and "collapse_key" options but they replace previous notification by the new one but i want  that new notifs append at the last notif box instead of replacing it or creating a new notif instance.
thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/managing.html

I can't just submit a link, so here's also a quote for you

> When you need to issue a notification multiple times for the same type of event, you should avoid making a completely new notification. Instead, you should consider updating a previous notification, either by changing some of its values or by adding to it, or both.
>
> The following section describes how to update notifications and also
>   how to remove them.

Comment: @Mohammad no, you got to have client support to edit notifications. Then, just send your clients messages that contain info about how notifications should be modified.